# Redirects in Flask/Werkzeug are not changing the URL

Tags: redirect, flask, werkzeug

I am very knew to python web development, so please bear with me.

I am trying setup a very basic log-in using Flask and the below code:

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
        if verifyLoggedIn():
                someData = gatherSomeData()
                return render_template('main.html', data=someData)
        else:
                return redirect(url_for('login'))

@app.route('/login/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.form['usr'] == user and request.form['pwd'] == password:
                session['user'] = request.form['usr']
                session['passwd'] = request.form['pwd']
                return redirect(url_for('index'))
        else:
                return render_template('out.html',name=request.form['usr'])
    else:
        return render_template('login.html')
```

When I access the page by going to 'localhost:5000/', I correctly get forwarded to 
'localhost:5000/login/'. After I log-in, however, the page loads 'main.html' but the url bar still shows 'localhost:5000/login/'. The problem with this, is that if I hit refresh button to get the new value of 'someData' I end up back at the log-in screen. I find that this is the case after any post action. Am I missing something very fundamental here?

Comment: Have you set a secret for you application (Flask's sessions won't work without them)?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to those who responded, but after much more searching, I managed to find that the answer was already on stackoverflow :p (sorry, I really did look around a lot before asking)

[Url in browser not updated after call of redirect( url_for('xxx' )) in Flask with jQuery mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13868007/url-in-browser-not-updated-after-call-of-redirect-url-forxxx-in-flask-wit)

The problem was actually being caused by jquery mobile and my lack of a data-url attribute.

Answer (score 1):

The following code works for me, it's basically the same as what you're doing:

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template, session, redirect, url_for

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'sldkf'

@app.route('/')
def index():
    if session['user']:
        return render_template('main.html')
    else:
        return redirect(url_for('login'))

@app.route('/login/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user = 'test'
        password = 'test'
        if request.form['usr'] == user and request.form['pwd'] == password:
            session['user'] = request.form['usr']
            session['passwd'] = request.form['pwd']
            return redirect(url_for('index'))
        else:
            return render_template('login.html')
    else:
        return render_template('login.html')

@app.route('/logout/', methods=['GET'])
def logout():
    session['user'] = None
    return redirect(url_for('login'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check to see if the user is authenticated in your 'login' route.  If so redirect to the 'index' route using `return redirect(url_for('index'))`.